# Jquery tabs selection through different DOM elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-ui-tabs

I have 4 tabs on a page with the following code:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-brandy">BRANDY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-whisky">WHISKY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-gin">GIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-wine">WINE</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-brandy">
    <!-- Tab brandy contents -->
  </div>

  <div id="tab-whisky">
    <!-- Tab whisky contents -->
  </div>

  <!-- Similarly tab GIN and tab WINE -->
```

There is a button element like this, inside the tab-brandy:

```
 <button id="#moveToWhisky">WHISKY</button>
```

I wanted to change the tab to "`tab-whisky"` when button with id `"#moveToWhisky"` was clicked.

So here was the script for that:

```
//Document ready
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    var tabOpts = {
     selected: 1
    };
    $("#Tabs").tabs(tabOpts);
  });
```

The above method did not work, so I tried this:

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
      $("#tabs").tabs("select", 2) //2 is tab number
  });
```

So finally did this:

```
    $("#moveToWhisky").click(function(){
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", 2);
     });
```

Nothing seems to work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the active tab, you need to call [the option method to change the value of *active*](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active):

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now. Wait accepting your answer. The book I studied did not have the active option anywhere under tabs. Once again thanks.